# PHP MySQL Transaction catch error

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, commit, rollback

I have been looking for two days now and still haven't found the answer. Suppose I have underneath code in PHP:

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM Test WHERE ID=1");
mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM TEST WHEREE ID=2"); <-- THIS ONE WILL FAIL BECAUSE OF TYPO
mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM Test WHERE ID=3");
if ($mysqli->commit()) {
    //SUCCESS
    }
else {
    //Failed        
    $mysqli->rollback();
    }
```

I am not able to check whether the queries within the transaction all have succeeded, because when I execute these queries, the commit function always returns true.

How can I check whether **all** queries within the transaction have succeeded?

Comment: Enclose the commit into a try / catch structure.

Comment: And rollback inside catch

Comment: Could you give me an example? How should I catch a unique error message for each query? Do I have to check each query separately in the transaction, will this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common way to do this:

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
try {
    mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM Test WHERE ID=1");
    mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM TEST WHEREE ID=2"); <-- THIS ONE WILL FAIL BECAUSE OF TYPO
    mysqli_query($mysqli, "DELETE FROM Test WHERE ID=3");
    $mysqli->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // this will show statement with error
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $mysqli->rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: I tried this already, but this will commit since it won't catch an exception?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  `$mysqli->commit();` should be immediately *before* `catch` so that if anything fails, whether query or commit, we make a desperate attempt to try to roll back.

Comment: Yes you're right, in common there may be errors while commit, but it's very specific errors in concurrence queries, not this case with invalid syntax

Answer (score -1):

You can use mysqli_error for catching the error.

```
$startTrans = 'START TRANSACTION;';  // Starting a mysql transaction
mysqli_query($conn, $startTrans); 

$query = 'Insert into students (roll_no,name,class) VALUES (101,"mathew","fourth")';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
if (mysqli_error($conn)) {
   // Rollback can be done here 
   mysqli_query($conn, "ROLLBACK;"); // All above queries will get rolled back
   die(mysqli_error($conn)); 
} else {
   mysqli_query($conn, "COMMIT;"); // changes will get saved to database
}
```